# Как реализовать безопасное выполнение пользовательского скрипта на сервере?

Tags: скрипт, php

Суть такова: нужно разрешить пользователям выполнять на сервере скрипт, такой, чтобы невозможно было навредить (залить шелл, залезть в базу, итд). Скрипт будет использоваться для обработки текста в сообщениях.

Есть ли некое подобие "песочницы" на пхп, на серверной части?

Comment: хм. а скрипт на каком языке? может, реализовать свой простой язык окажется проще, чем заткнуть все потенциальные угрозы для например скрипта на перле. ну или chroot + выполнение из-под специального юзера без home и с обрезанными правами.

Comment: Без разницы какой язык, желательно похожий на пхп, либо яваскрипт

Comment: @VladD поддерживаю! Сочинить что-то на подобии smarty и написать обработчик.

Comment: Ну, js -- хорошая идея. Если глобальным объектом будет обрабатываемый текст (то есть, выполнение нужно на кастомном движке, не из-под браузера), у скрипта просто не будет возможности доступа к файловой системе и вообще куда не позволено. (Конкретную реализацию подсказать не смогу.)

Comment: @Palmervan: а что такое smarty? Простите моё невежество.

Comment: @VladD Простите мое невежество) [синтаксис][1] использовать к примеру как у [smarty][2], и к нему обработчик


  [1]: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.basic.syntax.tpl
  [2]: http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: Оставьте только строковые и математические функции, а остальные беспощадно запрещайте, также запретите два знака доллара подряд и разрешите использовать для хранения данных только массив с неким выделенным именем.  
Возможно, этого хватит.  
Это про PHP.

Comment: @Palmervan: спасибо, буду просвещаться! :)